# React-Router 4: Route all 404 paths except 'manifest.json' and 'sitemap.xml'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have my react-router config as defined below

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from '../Home'
import AboutUs from '../containers/AboutUs'

const Router = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path='/aboutUs' component={AboutUs}/>
      <Route path='*' exact component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  </main>
)

export default Router
```

I'm trying to route `404` routes back to home page. This works fine, but after adding this `<Route path='*' exact component={Home} />` route, I'm not able to access

1. www.mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml
2. www.mywebsite.com/manifest.json

They are also routed to the Home Page. So basically what I'm trying to achieve is to route all `Not Found` routes to home page except for `xml or json` files

Answer (score 1):

I removed `exact` from `*` path and it worked